# Creating a development graph in R using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I wish to create a development graph, which is as follows. Let me first present to you the dataset:

```
library(lubridate)
test_data <- data.table(
  RunDate = c("2019-12-31", "2019-12-31", "2019-12-31", "2019-12-31",
              "2018-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2018-12-31",
              "2017-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2017-12-31"),
  ID = c(1, 2, 7, 8,
         1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9,
         1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  Value = c(90, 43, 51, 99,
            100, 23, 52, 43, 14, 41,
            91, 131, 41, 12, 51, 11),
  IrrelevantColumn = c(1, 421, 321, 12, 43, 767, 42, 34, 12, 55, 22, 42)
)

inputDates <- "RunDate"
inputID <- "ID"
inputValues <- "Value"
```

If we examine the dataset, we see that from 2017 to 2018:

1. people with the following IDs are "gone" in 2018: 1 (91), 2 (131), 3 (41). Thus, the effect would be -(91+131+41) = -263.
2. people with the following IDs are "new" in 2018: 9 (41), results in an effect of +41
3. people that have increased in the value: 4 (52 - 12 = 40), 6 (14 - 11 = 3), which results in an effect of +43.
4. people that have decreased in value: 5 (43 - 51 = -8), which results in an effect of -8.

The resulting table would be:

```
Year | Movement | Value
2017 | In       | +41
2017 | Out      | -263
2017 | Increase | +43
2017 | Decrease | -8
```

However, the problem is, I would like to do this for every year, but currently I first split the data.table for those two years and then merge them on ID, which is not very efficient if we have many years. I was wondering whether we could do this more efficiently in data.table.

Comment: The words don't match the data, but I think I get it. One question, if someone goes, can they come back later?

Comment: Yes, that's totally possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realised I've done it basically the same way you say at the end of your question.

```
library(data.table)
test_data <- data.table(
  RunDate = c("2019-12-31", "2019-12-31", "2019-12-31", "2019-12-31",
    "2018-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2018-12-31",
    "2017-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2017-12-31"),
  ID = c(1, 2, 7, 8,
    4, 5, 6, 9,
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  Value = c(90, 43, 51, 99,
    52, 43, 14, 41,
    91, 131, 41, 12, 51, 11)
  )

rundates <- sort(unique(test_data[,RunDate]))
rundates_map <- shift(rundates)
names(rundates_map) <- rundates

x <- merge(
  test_data[,.(RunDate = rundates_map[RunDate], ID, addition = Value)][!is.na(RunDate)],
  test_data[,.(RunDate, ID, subtraction = -Value)],
  by = c('RunDate','ID'),
  all = TRUE
)
y <- x[, .(
  In = sum(ifelse(is.na(subtraction), addition, 0)),
  Out = sum(ifelse(is.na(addition), subtraction, 0)),
  Increase = as.numeric(sum(ifelse(addition+subtraction > 0, addition+subtraction, 0), na.rm = TRUE)),
  Decrease = as.numeric(sum(ifelse(addition+subtraction < 0, addition+subtraction, 0), na.rm = TRUE))
), .(RunDate)]

melt(y,'RunDate', c('In', 'Out', 'Increase', 'Decrease'), 'Movement', 'Value')[order(RunDate)]
#>        RunDate Movement Value
#>  1: 2017-12-31       In    41
#>  2: 2017-12-31      Out  -263
#>  3: 2017-12-31 Increase    43
#>  4: 2017-12-31 Decrease    -8
#>  5: 2018-12-31       In   283
#>  6: 2018-12-31      Out  -150
#>  7: 2018-12-31 Increase     0
#>  8: 2018-12-31 Decrease     0
#>  9: 2019-12-31       In     0
#> 10: 2019-12-31      Out  -283
#> 11: 2019-12-31 Increase     0
#> 12: 2019-12-31 Decrease     0
```

Comment: Ah yes, but you have done it much better, as I was splitting two data.tables for every pair of years! I do have one small question though, as an extension to my previous problem. Would it be possible not doing it with `year -1`, but using a method to select the previous "date value" of the dataset?

Comment: Yeah, I just changed it. It's a bit fiddly and you lose the 2016 changes (unless you put an extra date in the `rundates_map`.